# are permutation coordinate of a point linear independent under cyclic group with odd length?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

suppose we have a cyclic group $C_{k}$ with odd length . if this group act on a point in $R^{k}$ with permutation coordinate, how I can show this points are linearly independent? if they are not can you give me an example?

for example if $C_{3}=<(1,2,3),e,(1,3,2)>$ acts on $(10,12,0)\in R^{3}$ then $(0,10,12)$ , $(10,12,0)$ and $(12,0,10)$ are linearly independent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if you cyclically permute the entries in $(1, 0, -1)$?

If you start with any $k$ dimensional vector whose coordinates sum to $0$ then the sum of the $k$ permuted vectors will be $0$, so they won't be independent.

I suspect that they will be independent if the entries are positive. For linear independence that's equivalent to the sum being nonzero since you can add a constant vector to everything and not change the conclusion.

I'll leave it to someone else to provide a proof.

Edit. This turns out to be deeper and more interesting problem than I thought. The wikipedia page on circulant matrices provides this:

> The polynomial $f(x)=c_{0}+c_{1}x+\dots +c_{{n-1}}x^{{n-1}}$ is called
>   the associated polynomial of matrix $C$.
>
> The rank of a circulant matrix $C$ is equal to $n − d$ , where $d$  is the degree of $\gcd  (f(x),x^{n} -1)  $.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix

Comment: how about if they are all positive?

Comment: See my edit....

Comment: if the sum of coordinates are not to 0 , then can they be linear independent?

Comment: As I wrote, I think they will be independent when the coordinate sum is nonzero.

Comment: do you know how I should start to proof that? I think they are linear independent but I dont know how I can show that! should I work with determinant or should I find a pattern for reducing the matrix

Comment: thank you, you helped me a lot.

Comment: If $n = 4$, the vector (1,2,1,2) gives a problem. I think this is due to the fact that 4 has divisor 2 and thus you can produce a repeating pattern in the vector. Therefore I think another condition, apart from the entries being positive, has to be that $n$ is a prime number.